# Pisot conjugates

Tags: nt.number-theory

An informal version of my question is "If we have a Pisot number between 1 and 2 of a very large degree, is it true that all its other conjugates are very close to 1 in modulus?"

A more formal version is as follows: let $\beta_n\in(1,2)$ be a convergent sequence of [Pisot numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pisot%E2%80%93Vijayaraghavan_number) with $d_n$ being the degree of $\beta_n$ and $\gamma^{(n)}_1,\dots, \gamma^{(n)}_{d_n-1}$ be the Galois conjugates of $\beta_n$ which are different from $\beta_n$. We have then by definition, $|\gamma_k^{(n)}|<1$ for all $n\ge1$ and all $k=1,\dots,d_n-1$. Put 
$$
\mu_n=\min_{1\le k\le d_n-1} |\gamma_k^{(n)}|. 
$$
**Question.** Is it true that $\mu_n\to1$ as $n\to\infty$?

EDIT. For those familiar with the literature, this claim can be proved directly for the so-called *regular Pisot numbers* $\beta=\lim_{n\to\infty}\beta_n$. Unfortunately, there exist other (irregular) Pisot numbers which may or may not accumulate at 2. This class does not appear to exhibit any pattern. So I've been wondering if there is a way to prove this without addressing this issue.

ADDED EXAMPLE. I think it might be helpful to give an example. Let $\beta_n$ be the $n$th multinacci number, i.e., the root of $x^{n+1}-2x^n+1$ lying between 1 and 2. Let $\gamma=\gamma_k^{(n)}$ be one of its conjugates. We have $\gamma^{n+1}=2\gamma^n-1$, whence 
$$
|\gamma^{-n}|=\left|\frac2{\gamma}-1\right|\le \left|\frac2{\gamma}\right|+1\le5,
$$
since $|\gamma|\ge\frac12$.
Thus, $|\gamma|\ge 1/\sqrt[n]5\to1$ as $n\to\infty$. This works so well here, because $\beta_n$ is a root of a polynomial with small coefficients and a small number of nonzero coefficients. It is unclear whether this is always the case.

ADDED "COUNTEREXAMPLE". Let now $\beta_n$ be the root of $x^n-x^{n-1}-\dots-x^2-x+1$ lying in $(1,2)$. Then $\beta_n$ is known to be a [Salem number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salem_number), which implies that $\gamma_n:=\beta_n^{-1}$ is one of its conjugates. (The rest are of modulus 1.) Thus, the result in question doesn't hold for this family, since $\gamma_n\to\frac12$ as $n\to\infty$. The trick from the previous example gives
$$
\gamma_n^{-n}=\frac{2-\gamma_n}{\gamma_n(2\gamma_n-1)},
$$
so we cannot claim $|\gamma_n^{-n}|=O(1)$, since $2\gamma_n-1\to0$. This example shows that the problem is rather delicate, since the conjecture is invalid even for a sequence of "close relatives" of Pisot numbers.

Comment: If $\beta$ is a Pisot number, then so is $\beta^m$, $m=2,3,\dots$, so high degree alone does not imply closeness to 1 in modulus.

Comment: Fair point, Gerry. OK, I restrict $\beta_n$ to $(1,2)$ which is actually the range I care about.

Comment: I believe there are Salem numbers less than, but arbitrarily close to, 2. Such Salem numbers necessarily have a conjugate close to $1/2$. If there's a way to find Pisot numbers that, together with their conjugates, shadow Salem numbers and their conjugates....

Comment: Indeed, there are such Salem numbers. For instance, the dominant roots of $x^n-x^{n-1}-x^{n-2}-\dots-x^2-x+1$. Also, the multinacci numbers which are the real roots of $x^n-x^{n-1}-x^{n-2}-\dots-x^2-x-1$ exhibit the property in question. However, I don't see at the moment how to check this shadowing property for the conjugates. Are there any general approaches to this?

Comment: I'm not on top of that, I only know that David Boyd did some work on Salem numbers as limits of sequences of Pisot numbers, and others have continued that work. Boyd conjectured that the union of the Salems and Pisots is a closed set, which I think is still an open question.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Your first remark is relevant to an earlier version of the question which did not restrict the limit to $(1,2)$. It is nice, but how does it show that there is a convergent series $\beta_n$  where the conjecture fails?

Comment: @Aaron, it was only intended to show, in answer to part of the version of the question that was up at the time, that high degree alone does not imply closeness to 1 in modulus. It says nothing about the current version, nor about the convergent sequence $\beta_n$, but I leave it there since Nikita responded to it.

Comment: Just to note regarding your example that it is a general fact that the coefficients of the minimum polynomial of a Pisot number in $(1,2)$ are sub-exponentially small in the degree $n$. Hence, generalizing your example mildly, your question certainly has an affirmative answer for the Pisot polynomials of the form $P(x) = 1 \pm x^kQ(x)$, where $k \sim n$ (i.e., $\deg{Q} = o(k)$), and whose dominant root belongs to $(1,2)$ as you require. Or say whose multiple $(1-x)P(x)$ or $(1-x^2)P(x)$ have this form. E.g. Siegel's constructions of Pisot numbers accumulating to the Golden Mean are such.

Comment: @VesselinDimitrov, What you describe is pretty much the regular Pisot numbers. Unfortunately, there exist irregular Pisot numbers; it is known that for any $\delta>0$, there are only finitely many of those in $(1,2-\delta)$ and there is an algorithm due do D. Boyd which - at least, in theory - allows to list them all in any $(a,b)\subset(1,2)$ with $b<2$. It is not known if there are infinitely many irregulars in $(1,2)$. For more details see, e.g., https://arxiv.org/abs/1103.2147

Comment: In view of your newest edit, do you have any particular reason to believe in this statement, still referred to as a conjecture here? It seems a rather strong one, at least if you extend it to an arbitrary fixed interval such as $[1,10]$ say (maybe $[1,2]$ is special in view of your comments on irregular Pisot numbers). But we do know the affirmative answer for the regular Pisot numbers as you note, as well as for the lacunary Pisot polynomials $P$: the ones whose first non-zero non-constant term is in degree $(1-o(1))\deg{P}$.

Comment: @VesselinDimitrov We don't know much about the structure of $S\cap (2, \infty)$, so I guess we don't have a particular reason to believe this claim to be true. Having elements of $S''$ may add extra complications, for instance.

Comment: @NikitaSidorov: Personally I would guess against this claim, but I don't have anything substantive to say at the moment. It feels like much too strong a statement, but who knows. If you believe in it then you may wonder even more generally whether the same would hold for any sequence of Pisot numbers with heights approaching zero, i.e. with $\log{|\alpha|} = o(\deg{\alpha})$.